# Adding bytes to the end of a register value

Tags: arm

Ok so basically I'm trying to add two strings together character by character.

I go through each char of the first string until I reach the end

Then I go through each char of the next string too

My problem is trying to store the characters of the next string to the first string (before the 0 terminating byte).

```
strcat
    ADD R4, R4, #1
    LDRB R0, [R1], #1
    CMP R0, #0
    BNE strcat
    SUB R4, R4, #1      ;take byte pointer 1 step back to ignore 0
    B stradd

stradd  
    LDRB R0, [R2], #1   ;otherwise we would include the 0 char
    STRB R0, [R1], R4
    CMP R0, #0
    ADD R4, R4, #1
BNE stradd      ;keep adding chars
```

Is my method so far, It is trying to concatenate R1 + R2

**Question**

How to I change the STRB (or other method entirely) to make sure that it starts saving bytes at the address of the last proper character of the string in R1

**Example**
If the chars in R1 looked like
'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' 0
and chars in R2 looked like 
'y' 'u' 'o'

The method should change the chars in R1 to
'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' 'y' 'u' 'o' 0

Comment: And your question is what precisely?

Comment: Oops, Good point, shall edit now

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it .. in case someone sees this later :)

Answer (score 1):

I have since asked a friend who provided this solution

There is no need to use R4 to track the char position. Instead a more elegant solution to exclude the 0 of the first string and concatenate is:

```
strcat
    LDRB R0, [R1], #1
    CMP R0, #0
    BNE strcat
SUB R1, R1, #1

stradd  
    LDRB R0, [R2], #1   ;otherwise we would include the 0 char
    STRB R0, [R1], #1
    CMP R0, #0
    BNE stradd      ;keep adding chars
```